# Displaying custom fields in a forum

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, forum, drupal-fields

I have made some custom fields at config->account settings (manage fields) and I have put them in my registration form but I want some of them display at image I show below under the post count and generally when they create a new topic or replay.

How do I display that field? From a search I did I found that it's inside the module VIEWS. I am searching inside there to find where to add the field.

[image]

Comment: I want to be able to do this exact thing!

Comment: By the way, have you seen this page? Similar problem? http://drupal.org/node/709538

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation page: http://drupal.org/node/367306